# Error in z[, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions when doing Jackknife resampling

Tags: r

I am using a ratio of means to estimate the population, Stat = mean(xbar)/ mean(u_bar) using jackknife method (The jackknife estimator of a parameter is found by systematically leaving out each observation from a dataset and calculating the estimate and then finding the average of these calculations), in this case i want to leave out one row each time I make a sample.  my code gives this error

> Error in z[, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions

```
pop = read_xlsx("US_pop.xlsx")
attach(pop)
z = cbind(X,U)
n=length(z)
resam=matrix(0,n,n-1)
for(i in 1:n) r#apply to each row
resam[i,]=z[-i]

## STAT function
Stat = function(z) mean(z[, 1])/mean(z[,2])
apply(resam,1,Stat)
```

Comment: You have `resam[i,]=z[-i]`.  I think that you are trying to leave out the ith row, so you need `resam[i,]=z[-i, ]`

Comment: I tried to use resam[i,]=z[-i, ] and i'm still getting the same error